# How to use Spring Security's RoleHierarchy with Vaadin?

Tags: spring-security, vaadin

I'm trying to make use of a `RoleHierarchy` in Vaadin 23.3.

```java
public class WebUISecurity extends VaadinWebSecurity {
    // ...
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
        roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER");
        DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
        http.authorizeRequests().expressionHandler(expressionHandler);
        super.configure(http);
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class, "/ui/login");
    }
    // ...
}
```

But the `RoleHierarchy` isn't used at all: When accessing a restricted Vaadin view is accessed (`@RolesAllowed("USER")`), a breakpoint in `getReachableGrantedAuthorities(...)` isn't hit.

Am I doing something wrong or is there anything to consider when using Vaadin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that the approach using the expression handler doesn't make sense, as the `@RoleAllowed`-annotations are checked using `ViewAccessChecker`. As this class uses `HttpServletRequest#isUserInRole(...)` to check the roles, an approach is to make use of an `RoleHierarchyAuthoritiesMapper` in the corresponding `AuthenticationProvider` or in your `LdapAuthoritiesPopulator`.

```java
@Bean
@Conditional(DummyUserCondition.class)
public DaoAuthenticationProvider dummyUserAuthenticationProvider(
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager dummyUserDetailsService, RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy) {
    var provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(dummyUserDetailsService);
    provider.setAuthoritiesMapper(new RoleHierarchyAuthoritiesMapper(roleHierarchy));
    return provider;
}
```

see https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/16621#issuecomment-1514625986